# Control the data facebook fetch and post on "share"

Tags: social-network, meta-tags

I am building a drupal 7 site using [Addthis module](https://drupal.org/project/addthis), [Meta tag module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Open Graph meta tag module](https://drupal.org/project/opengraph_meta)

When clicking on the facebook share button - facebook fetch the relevant image properly, but a lot of text data.

Some data is duplicated data. 
For example, the author name is fetched twice (e.g. "Admin Admin")

In addition, the labels of the field are fetch as well. 
For example: "description: text text text". 
I prefer without the label: "text text text".

How can I control the text data / fields that facebook fetch? 
prevent duplicated data? 
 prevent fetching the labels?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that on the admin -> configuration -> Metatag -> open-graph. 
 I had the token [node:summary] on the description field. 
I do not have a field on my site called summary.
This token just fetch a lot of information from the content / view and post it.

I removed it, change it to tokens I wanted, add some text to make the output more readable, and that's it.

After that, it took time for the site to update with the changes..